# Why i am getting a role exception?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
class Admin(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='create-embed')
    @commands.has_role(env.METACORE_MODERATOR_ROLE_ID)
    async def create_embed(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        embed_title = 'Test title'
        view = embed.view.CreateEmbedView()
        view.bot = self.bot
        view.author_id = ctx.author.id
        result_embed = discord.Embed(title=embed_title)
        embed_message = await ctx.send(embed=result_embed, view=view, ephemeral=True)
        view.embed = result_embed
        view.embed_message = embed_message

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Admin(bot))
```

So I have this code, `env.METACORE_MODERATOR_ROLE_ID = 1019323835100700732`.
I gave a role with this id on my server, but I got the error -

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRole: Role '1019323835100700732' is required to run this command.
```

And when I call ctx.message.author.roles, I am getting this role in array roles of user

And I don't understand why I am getting this error.
Thx for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse it as an integer.

[@commands.has_role()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role) can take role names aswell, so since it's a string your passing, discord.py assumes that the role name is "1019323835100700732"

You should do this instead:

```py
@commands.has_role(int(env.METACORE_MODERATOR_ROLE_ID))
```